# Was the Meta Reviews button always there?

Tags: support

I just noticed that at the bottom of the [reviews page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) there is a link to meta reviews. Has that always been there? I don't remember it being there before.

Also, can we get a normal reviews link on the meta reviews page?